# Some keyboard keys do not work after Ubuntu 20.04 update

Tags: 20.04, updates, update-manager

I updated some applications on my machine after being prompted by the OS. Today, however, I noticed that a few keys on my keyboard do not work i.e. backspace, pagedown, arrow key down, and left.

I think the problem is that I shut down my machine while the update was still ongoing

I have tried to continue the update process but when I start the installation I get this

[image]

Please is there a way I could resolve this?

Comment: it will be impossible to reproduce without further details of the applications involved and the underlying keyboard/language settings. Please [edit] you question with more specific detail.

Comment: Hello @24601. I have updated the question

Comment: back up anything important and re-install? Maybe move to 22.04.1 LTS